# How to know if a name refers to mysql table or mysql view in a php script

Tags: php, mysql

I can select all tables in a database like this

```
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  $tables[] = $row[0];
}
```

And following code populate $return variable which can be used to backup the database.

```
  foreach($tables as $table)
  {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
        $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
        {
          $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
          $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
          if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
          if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
        }
        $return.= ");\n";
      }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
  }
```

My database has two mysql views. Above code generates "INSERT INTO...." string even for mysql views which I need to avoid.
So before starting the 'for loop' to generate "INSERT INTO.." values I need to check if $table is actually a mysql table or view.
How to identify whether a name refers to mysql table or mysql view?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES
```

The `FULL` modifier is supported such that `SHOW FULL TABLES` displays a second output column. Values for the second column are `BASE TABLE` for a table and `VIEW` for a view.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the command [`SHOW FULL TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html), which will add a second column, showing if the relation is a `BASE TABLE` or `VIEW`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to detect whether a table/view exists. If so, the following should help. I have written a wrapper class for PDO and this statement has been taken from the `tables_exists()` method:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = :database AND TABLE_NAME = :table
```

The above query can be altered very easily to determine whether a view exists as well.

### Additional Note

Please do not use the `mysql_*` API as these functions are now deprecated. Instead, you should use either PDO or mysqli. See the following links:

1. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
2. [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA may not be available on a shared host so the only 'safe' method is the SHOW FULL TABLES. Just pointing out a trap that ppl may fall into :-)